# What is the efficient way to solve "no version information available" when an old shared object (so) is linked to a newer shared object (so)?

Tags: arch-linux, libraries, pacman

**Context**: Arch Linux
**Package Manager**: pacman

Running nearly any `pacman` command yields a warning:

```
pacman: /opt/plexmediaserver/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/libalpm.so.10)
```

I have seen solutions floating around and bug reports, but how can an admin solve this until the next updates roll in? **I am hear to learn admin thought processes, and not looking for minimalist answers.**

1. remove the symbolic link and risk breaking dependencies?
2. install an older version and have two versions installed?
3. revert to an older version (`pacman -U pkgname` from `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/`) and add name of pkg to IgnPackage section of `/etc/pacman.conf`?
4. wait and hope for the best?
5. some other technique?

## Filesystem Output `ls -lsa /usr/lib/libcurl*`

It is clear that libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.5.0* are linked.

```
  0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 23. Okt 13:27 libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.5.0*
  0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 23. Okt 13:27 libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.5.0*
520 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 530656 23. Okt 13:28 libcurl.so.4.5.0*
```

Comment: When was your last update of plex-media-server?

Comment: @ctx I see where you are going with that question, but I‘d prefer to focus on an admin‘s decision-making when updates are not (yet) available.

Comment: "I will not accept ’upgrade your packages’ as an answer." You are using a rolling release distribution, and yet you refuse to accept the only legitimate response as an answer...

Comment: @jasonwryan Because that is the cheapest cop-out of an answer.   Rolling releases have issues sometimes. Consider the unrelated and recent Nextcloud<PHP7.2 compatibility issue.  So no, upgrading is not the only legitimate response. Anyway, you should be able to see from my accepted answer that ctx took the time to provide steps and suggestions. This is a more detailed answer that I would accept, and it was accepted long before your comment by the way. I welcome new ideas, of course.

Comment: The answer you accepted (correctly), is just an expanded version of "upgrade your packages"...

Comment: Then please remove that stipulation from the question, it doesn't provide anything positive, and will not help future readers of the wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps, when you have a non working aur package:

- Rebuild the aur package, it might link to the new version of the library.
- Update the aur package if the maintainer updated the PKGBUILD
- If it doesn't help, update/fix the PKGBUILD
- If you fail to do so, install the old version and wait.
- If you need to update other packages, remove the aur package in question.

The first step catches sonamebumps. In other cases you really should update or remove the aur package. You should not wait, if there is a new PKGBUILD available.

If you really want to stay at a specific version, do only step one and three.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of posterity, I have found the real culprit. The truth is that at the time of writing the question, I misunderstood the problem.

## Solution

During some experiments, I had added `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/plexmediaserver` to my bash profile.

I just had to remove that. The shared library path went back to normal (`/usr/lib`) and life went back to normal.

I figured this out by running `printenv` as the right user.